# laravel route with store function controller

Tags: laravel

i created a resource route like :

```
Route::resource('club.user' , 'UserClubController');
```

to create users from a club . everything is fine when i want to display the blade view 'create' but when i want to store the user i get an error like :

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: club.user.store] [URI: club/{club}/user]. (View: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/adminlte/resources/views/users/createUserClub.blade.php)
```

Here my blade view to create a new user for the club :

```
  {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'club.user.store' , 'method' => 'POST')) !!}
```

here my function create from the UserClubController

```
public function create($club)
    {

        $club = Club::findOrFail($club);
        $role = Role::pluck('title' , 'id') ;
        return view('users/createUserClub' , compact('role' , 'club'));

    }
```

here my store Controller :

```
 public function store(Request $request){
        $user = new User;
        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));

        $type_structure = TypeStructure::where('id' , '=' , '4')->first();
        $user->type_structure_id = $type_structure->id;
        dd($user);
        $user->save();
```

someone have an idea to resolve this issue ? thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

It's basically exactly what the error tells you. You are using Route::resource and a nested model (club -> has many users)

If you now want to use

```
Route::resource('club.user' , 'UserClubController');
```

It means that every access to a user is via the specific club. You will therefore have the following routes

```
/club/{club}/user | GET, POST
/club/{club}/user/{user} | GET, PUT / PATCH, DELETE
```

You will need to provide this club paramter within your blade view

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => ['club.user.store', $club->id] , 'method' => 'POST')) !!}
```

Comment: thanks a lot Frank with the route param like you told me to use : ['club.user.store', $club->id] it's working and i get the right store controller ! thanks so much once again Frank !!!!!!